# How to dispatch function to gui thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I write custom worker component and want it to fire it's events on GUI thread. But I don't want it to know about any existing windows. Also sometimes I have moments when there's no window at all (transition between login and main window). So I can't use Window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(). What are the other ways?

Comment: Check out the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: How about using another GUI element? e.g myButton.invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass (or get using `Current`) a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) to your worker. This is a lower level threading object that represent a particular context of execution (usually a thread), onto which you can post custom actions using the `Post` method. In case of a WPF application, `SynchronizationContext.Post` will use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. It's a good way to write background components that invoke events or send messages to a specific context without being tied to a particular implementation.

Plus, it's very easy to write a synchronous `SynchronizationContext` that doesn't use threads at all to easily unit test your component without adding any asynchronous complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Great article on MSDN Magazine's WPF Threads section: [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Contents:
  - Threading in WPF
  - Using the Dispatcher
  - Non-UI thread handling
  - Using timers

(Sorry can't format list perfectly from my phone's browser)